# How to skip to a new line in a file and repeat loop?

Tags: c++, loops, fstream

I'm trying to read in data from a file that looks like this:

```
1 1 2007 12 31 2006
12 31 2007 1 1 2008
1 3 2006 12 15 2006
2 29 1900 3 1 1900
9 31 2007 10 28 2009
```

I'm using a function to read it in groups of 3 `int`s since the values are supposed to be dates, with 2 dates per line. If the first date of the pair returns an error, I need to skip to the next line and repeat the loop starting there, and if there isn't an error simply evaluate the next group. The file and `bool` variable for error are being passed into the `Get_Date()` function as reference parameters so they change accordingly outside of the function. I tried using `ignore()` and a `break` statement like so:

```
while (infile) {
   Get_Date(infile, inmonth1, inday1, inyear1, is_error);
   if (is_error == true){
      infile.ignore(100, '\n');
      break;
   } 
   if (is_error == false) {
      Get_Date(infile, inmonth2, inday2, inyear2, is_error);
      if (is_error == false) {
         Get_Date(infile, inmonth2, inday2, inyear2, is_error);
         other stuff; 
      } 
   }    
}
```

This just makes the entire program terminate after it gets 1 error, on the 4th line since Feb only has 29 days in a leap year. I thought that break would return control to the nearest loop, but that doesn't seem to be what is happening.

Comment: If the first date failed to read correctly, you should call `std::getline()` to chomp up to the end of the line. If the second fails, you should have already by this point consumed to the end of the line so you have nothing to do...

Comment: Please improve the readability of your code by removing all that redundant whitespace in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `continue` to skip execution of the rest of the cycle once you find an error:

```
while (infile) 
{
    Get_Date(infile, inmonth1, inday1, inyear1, is_error);
    if (is_error)
    {
        //Skip the rest of the line  (we do not know how long it is)
        infile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
        continue; //Skip the rest of the cycle
    } 

    Get_Date(infile, inmonth2, inday2, inyear2, is_error);
    if (is_error) { continue; } //Skip the other stuff if we have error

    otherStuff(); 
}
```

You can find some more information under *Jump statements* here : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/